# Analytic query( like count query ) is causing performance issue in Apache Phoenix

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

We have Hadoop cluster contains Phoenix table over HBase service and supporting 10k QPS. While running analytic query in the same table like count, group by for some operational purpose it's causing huge fluctuation in QPS(some time's 0 also). So to avoid can we enable any queue for analytical queries so that it won't disturb OLATP resources.

cluster size is 18 nodes( each 128 GB RAM + 32 vCPU) and data size is 300 GB(around 3 billion records).

Comment: Removed big-data tag. 300 GB fits on my 10+ year old laptop with 4GB of RAM and 2 cores. In any case, we don't know what heap sizes or resource management allocated specifically for your RegionServers, for example

Comment: This was initial data size, size will increase over days, anyway as of now we configured 12 GB heap.

Comment: I assume you are using YARN, so have you looked into its queuing and scheduler options? Or perhaps Phoenix/HBase isn't the best option for your queries, and maybe Druid/Pinot or Impala would be more preferred?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I too was getting same kind of issue. Phoenix query is not using yarn for it's execution.   OLTP  queries alone are running fine but when executing OLAP queries it's affecting the OLTP queries and time taken for the OLAP queries will be more.  (both type for queries will run over same channel(jdbc))

Answer (score 0):

hbase is not specifically optimized for statistical analysis.

If it is a complex algorithm distributed computing, just the task scheduling will have a lot of time consumption.

You might want to take a closer look at the data physical IO requirements of different business code to identify performance bottlenecks,